# Cambiar el icono de mi App

Tags: flutter, yaml

Quiero un nuevo icono en mi app flutter, ya cambie la dirección de la imagen nueva que quiero poner en el archivo pubspec.yaml. y el actualice el flutter pub get y aun sigue sin salir el icono nuevo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Agrega tu archivo o una imagen de como definiste la dirección de la imagen por favor.

Comment: Lo logre ejecutando flutter clean y flutter pub get despues de eso cambio mi icono

Comment: Pero como lo trataste de realizar, agregalo a tu pregunta por favor. @YeryValiente